# Need to open and write a DBASE4 table. Which Delphi route please?

Tags: delphi, dbase

I've a need to open and append a DBASE4 table with Delphi (7 and 2009/10). Presently it is done using home-rolled code. I presume this task is easy with Delphi, but which link mechanism should I use? I understand that the BDE is old and less supported now, but I dont want additional DLL's and support files if possible. I'm using the professional version.
Bri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open source TDBF component - http://tdbf.sourceforge.net/.

Advantages:

- Free
- Simple
- Still maintained and developed
- Almost bug-free
- No overhead of BDE or other libraries

Answer (score 1):

If you try any of the commercial components, be sure to check you can get your money back if they don't work. DBASE was a sort of standard, but various packages introduced new index and field types. As you may not be able to get a dcu only version for testing, buying it to get the source only to find that it won't work for the files you have could be painful without the money back guarantee. Been there, got the refund.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the components on [Torry](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=564).net

I've used Halcyon in the past and it's pretty good.